# How do you provide SQL with your software to a client?

Tags: deployment, sql-server-express

I am new to SQL and I have a few silly questions I am wondering about.

I am a C# developer and have thus far only worked with access, .mdb files.

Let's say you develop some software for a client. It;s to be loaded on a few workstations and they need to connect to a central database.

When you use an .mdb file its pretty straight forward.

But how will you handle it if its SQL? Do you normally install SQL express on the server and just set the connection string in the software on the workstations. I've never heard of an easier way to get the SQL database up and running and available to be connected to. As far as I know you can't connect to a SQL database file like with an mdb file

Please help me understand a little bit better?

Comment: Is that web application (website) ? or Desktop application ?

Comment: Both, doesn't matter. My question is, is SQL express the best way to provide a client with a SQL database?

Comment: @Gillian , ahm it depends .. if that is a company running a business, you have to use a licensed SQL Server to be installed on clients server, because SQL express has a limited features. If that is for business , you have to use Professional Edition of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're going to deploy a web application, the SQL need to install in the server, then the website developer set their connection strings in the `web.config` file of the project, and the connection string is pointed to server.

you can read this regarding web.config: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx